# Differential equation modelling

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, mathematical-modeling

[image]

[image]

[image]

I want to know where I have gone wrong.

Please add a suitable title and tag.

Comment: I think your tags and title are just fine.

Comment: The parameter $k$ is the size of the population (100'000), not something to be estimated. And the evolution is not $N'=N(k-N)$ but $N'=aN(k-N)$ for some positive parameter $a$ which you must compute using the data.

Comment: Thanks , I got it. I forget the constant of propotionality.